# VB.net mySQL Insert query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Hey guys this is my db :
http://prntscr.com/39on8i

I get this error if I try to add something to my users1 table : 
 Unknown Column Nume in 'field list'

This is my VB code  :

'INSERT INTO config (id, customer_id, domain) 
        'SELECT DISTINCT id, customer_id, domain FROM config;'

```
    Try

        ' Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO presence(id_presence,id,hours,date) " & _
        '   "SELECT DISTINCT @Id_presence,@Id,@Hours,@Date FROM presence"


        'adding a new user

        Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO users1(id,Nume,Prenume,username,password,onedrive,access, id_dep, id_pontaj) " & _
    "VALUES (0,@Nume,@Prenume,@Username,@Password,@Onedrive,@Access,@Iddep,@Idpontaj)"


        Using con = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = accounts; Uid=root; Pwd = password")
            Using SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, con)
                con.Open()
                'SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                'SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_presence", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                'SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text))
                'SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text))
                'SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text))

                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", Convert.ToString(TextBox2.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenume", Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Convert.ToString(TextBox4.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Convert.ToString(TextBox5.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Onedrive", Convert.ToString(TextBox6.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Access", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iddep", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox7.Text))
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idpontaj", Convert.ToString(TextBox8.Text))


                SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(" Failure to communicate " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the ID is being seen as reserved (not sure why), but try and put square brackets around it in the field list [id]

Comment: Actually it was a typo, I did discover it now. At mysqlconnection, my database was users, not accounts. I've been messing around with some settings, thanks tho.